# REST POST HTTP JSON Objects 400 error Android

Tags: java, android, json, rest, http

Since I got some bad reviews I am rewriting this question...

I have an HTTP REST server and a client (Android app). I have programmed several APIs that work just fine, however there is one that is giving me a 400 error, and if I put a breakpoint in the server, it does not even triggers it. So, I would like to understand why it fails :( ...

It is very simple, I have a value object called Alarm with a few attributes, that I want to POST to the server for registration of object in the database.

This is the output:

```
 Callback failure for call to http://10.0.0.3:8080/...
 java.io.IOException: Unexpected code Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=, url=http://10.0.0.3:8080/BiTrack_API/api/assets/registerAlarm}
     at it.bitrack.fabio.bitrack.AlarmView$2$1.onResponse(AlarmView.java:438)
     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

This is my client side Android button listener:

```
View.OnClickListener addAlarmAction = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {

                alarm.setThreshold(Float.parseFloat(thresholdEditText.getText().toString()));
                String alarmJson = j.makeJsonBodyForAlarmRegistration(alarm);
                tagLinearLayout.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                operatorLinearLayout.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                thresholdLinearLayout.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                assetSpinner.setSelection(0);

                r.attemptAddNewAlarm(alarmJson,

                        new Callback() {
                            @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                                try (final ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
                                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                                    Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                                    for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                                        System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                                    }

                                    final String responseBodyString = responseBody.string();
                                    final int resultCode = response.code();

                                    try {

                                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {

                                                Log.i("BiTrack", "attemptAddNewAlarm RESULT: " + resultCode);
                                                executeAlarmRegistration(resultCode);

                                            }
                                        });

                                    } catch (Exception e) {

                                        e.printStackTrace();

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
    };
```

This is the code where I generate the Json body for the POST in the client:

```
public String makeJsonBodyForAlarmRegistration (Alarm alarm) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String jsonAlarm = gson.toJson(alarm);

        return jsonAlarm;

    }
```

This is the actual POST code in the client (Android) side:

```
public void attemptAddNewAlarm(String json, Callback callback) throws Exception {

        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(WEB_SERVER + "BiTrack_API/api/assets/registerAlarm")
                .post(body)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
    }
```

This is my server side code:

```
@POST
    @Path("/registerAlarm")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response registerAlarm(Alarm alarm) {

        System.out.println("Received API Call: registerAlarm for alarm tagId: " + alarm.getTagId() + " operatorId: " + alarm.getOperatorId() + " treshold: " + alarm.getThreshold());

        DataProcessor dp = new DataProcessor();
        AssetUpdateDAO aDAO = new AssetUpdateDAO();

        ArrayList<Alarm> customerAlarms = aDAO.getUserAlarmsForAsset(alarm.getUserId(), alarm.getAssetId());


        if (dp.isNewAlarmDuplicate(customerAlarms, alarm)) {

            return Response.status(480).build(); // duplicated error

        } else {

            int response = aDAO.insertAssetUserAlarm(alarm.getUserId(), alarm.getAssetId(), alarm.getTagId(), alarm.getOperatorId(), alarm.getThreshold());

            if (response == -5) {
                return Response.status(484).build(); // something went wrong while inserting alarm into db
            } else {
                return Response.status(200).build();
            }

        }

    }
```

This is my Alarm value object (identical class in client and server):

```
public class Alarm {

    public Alarm() {

    }

    protected int id;
    protected int userId;
    protected int assetId;
    protected int tagId;
    protected int operatorId;
    protected float threshold;
    protected String networkAssetCode;

    public String getNetworkAssetCode() {
        return networkAssetCode;
    }
    public void setNetworkAssetCode(String networkAssetCode) {
        this.networkAssetCode = networkAssetCode;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public int getAssetId() {
        return assetId;
    }
    public void setAssetId(int assetId) {
        this.assetId = assetId;
    }
    public int getTagId() {
        return tagId;
    }
    public void setTagId(int tagId) {
        this.tagId = tagId;
    }
    public int getOperatorId() {
        return operatorId;
    }
    public void setOperatorId(int operatorId) {
        this.operatorId = operatorId;
    }
    public float getThreshold() {
        return threshold;
    }
    public void setThreshold(float threshold) {
        this.threshold = threshold;
    }

}
```

I really appreciate any help...

Comment: Show us your code. Endpoint you are calling and entity this JSON should map to.

Comment: And on what basis do you think we should help you. Show us the code. We don't need theory classes.

Comment: @user1060551 Please show your code, So that we can help you.

Comment: I have posted the code can you please review it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue! After 48 hours looking for the impossible, discovered that I had done a small update at the object attribute at the server side that had not been replicated in the client side...

Answer (score 0):

In order to help you, the endpoint code is required. Now it is even unclear what technology stack is used for your API.

But from the information that is present... The endpoint considers your json as invalid.

> **400 Bad Request**
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>   syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.

In jax-rs the payload is first deserialized before it reaches the method that is bound to the url en http method.

Possibly the deserializing is failing and it never reaches the breakpoint you set.

What would be interesting is the following:

- logs or exception from the server. The client exception is not that helpful, since the server returns this response.
- the actual (json) payload that is send over the wire.
- what deserialization mechanism is used at the server end? Reflection or did you make your own deserializer?

Comment: I have posted the code can you please review it? Thank you!

Comment: I requested some additional info. I looks like you are using jax-rs at the server side. Do you perhaps know which implementation? Jersey, CXF, resteasy,... ? And which json de-/serailizer is configured at the server end? Jackson, Gson,... ?

Comment: On the server, using Jersey + Jackson

Comment: Good to know you solved it. Jackson most likely would have logged something (server side) that would pointed you in this correction.